# How to validate a checkbox in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I have a problem with validating a checkbox. I want to show error message if "submit" is clicked while checkbox is unchecked.
With the code I have right now, form gets submitted anyway. I've tried multiple code snippets I found from other questions but none seem to work..

HTML:

```
<?php include 'contact-form.php'; ?>

<form id="contact" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" 
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<h3>Add issue</h3>
<fieldset>
  <input placeholder="Nimi" type="text" tabindex="1" name="thename"  value="<?= $thename ?>" autofocus>
    <div class="error"><span><?= $name_error ?></span></div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <input placeholder="Email" type="text" tabindex="2" name="email" value="<?= $email ?>">
    <div class="error"><span><?= $email_error ?></span></div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="yes"/> Annan ühendusele loa minu eluloo avaldamiseks siinsel kodulehel. <br>
  <div class="error"><span><?= $checkbox1_error ?></span></div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

if (empty($_POST["thename"])) {
    $name_error = "Palun sisesta nimi";
} else {
    $thename = test_input($_POST["thename"]);
    // check if name only contains letters, whitespace and hyphen
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z -]*$/",$thename)) {
        $name_error = "Sisestada saab ainult tähti, tühikuid ja sidekriipse";
    }
}

if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
  $email_error = "Palun sisesta email";
} else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    // email validation
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $email_error = "Sisesta email korrektselt";
    }
}    

if(!isset($_POST['checkbox1'])) {
  //checkbox is not checked
  $checkbox1_error = 'Väli peab olema kinnitatud';
}

if ($name_error == '' and $email_error == '' and $message_error == '' and $attachment_error == '' and $checkbox1_error == ''){
    $message_body = '';
    unset($_POST['submit']);
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
        $message_body .= "$key: $value\n";
    }


    $to = 'myemail@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'My subject';
    $message = "My message";

if (@mail($to, '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($subject) . '?=', $datamsg, $headers, "-f$email")){
        $success = "Aitäh, kiri edukalt saadetud!";
    } else {
        $error = "Saatmine ebaõnnestus. Palun proovige uuesti.";
    }
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I believe checkboxes post as 'On'

Comment: `isset` should be enough. The value is not that important. If checkbox is not ticked then it will not be set in PHP.

Comment: @treyBake I dont think so, then the value itself would be useless. Do you do a post or get?

Comment: @KamranKB that's exactly what `<?= $checkbox1_error` does. It's a shorthand code for `<?php echo $checkbox1_error;`

Comment: kindly share the `<form>` tag code that what method you're using and what's the action of form

Comment: @J.Knabenschuh what? o.O That doesn't make any sense, why would that make the value useless? If unticked, it shows as 'Off'?

Comment: @empiric oops sorry so it would be better to validate it through jQuery rather than sending request to server

Comment: @KamranKB what? no, always validate on both client and server ..

Comment: Yes @treyBake always have to validate on both client and server side, In this scenario it should be validate through jQuery on client end and then on server side.

Comment: @treyBake You mean change 'Yes' to 'On'? Sadly that did not make any difference
@Dharman I tried chaning php code like this: 
`if(isset($_POST['checkbox1']) {
     $checkbox1_error = 'Väli peab olema kinnitatud';
 }` ,sadly that didn't make any difference.. Error is not showing :/

@KamranKB echo is no necessary in this situation.

Comment: @veskimati OK, new debug plan :p before those if's etc. - var_dump $_POST and see what is actually posted

Comment: @treyBake maybe I missunderstand. I though you mean that a ticked checkbox will always give the value "On" independent of the value given in value-attr. Then the value-attr is useless.

Comment: Is your PHP code  before or after the form?

Comment: They are in different files. I updated my question with more code (left out unnecessary parts)

Comment: `action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"` - That means that it's posting to itself. Are you using ajax? You need to edit your question and explain the flow in detail. Unless we know that (exactly how and when each code get's called etc), we can only throw guesses at you.

Comment: Not using ajax, pure HTML and PHP.

Comment: Do a `var_dump($_POST);` and see what actually gets posted.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code and its showing the error message for checkbox[image: The Image with Checkbox error]

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    if (empty($_POST["thename"])) {
        $name_error = "Palun sisesta nimi";
    } else {
        $thename = $_POST["thename"];
        // check if name only contains letters, whitespace and hyphen
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z -]*$/", $thename)) {
            $name_error = "Sisestada saab ainult tähti, tühikuid ja sidekriipse";
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $email_error = "Palun sisesta email";
    } else {
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        // email validation
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $email_error = "Sisesta email korrektselt";
        }
    }

    if (!isset($_POST['checkbox1'])) {
        //checkbox is not checked
        $checkbox1_error = 'Väli peab olema kinnitatud';
    }

    if (!isset($name_error) and ! isset($email_error) and ! isset($message_error) and ! isset($attachment_error) and ! isset($checkbox1_error)) {
        $message_body = '';
        unset($_POST['submit']);
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
            $message_body .= "$key: $value\n";
        }


        $to = 'myemail@gmail.com';
        $subject = 'My subject';
        $message = "My message";

        if (@mail($to, '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($subject) . '?=', $datamsg, $headers, "-f$email")) {
            $success = "Aitäh, kiri edukalt saadetud!";
        } else {
            $error = "Saatmine ebaõnnestus. Palun proovige uuesti.";
        }
    }
}
?>
<form id="contact" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" 
      enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h3>Add issue</h3>
    <fieldset>
        <input placeholder="Nimi" type="text" tabindex="1" name="thename"  value="<?php echo $_POST['thename'] ?>" autofocus>
        <div class="error"><span><?php echo $name_error ?></span></div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <input placeholder="Email" type="text" tabindex="2" name="email" value="<?php echo $_POST['email'] ?>">
        <div class="error"><span><?php echo $email_error ?></span></div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="yes"/> Annan ühendusele loa minu eluloo avaldamiseks siinsel kodulehel. <br>
        <div class="error"><span><?php echo $checkbox1_error ?></span></div>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Sadly this is not working. Still no error message shown.. :/

Comment: Can you send me the full code?

Comment: I updated my question with more code (left out unnecessary parts)

Comment: change this section `if ($name_error == '' and $email_error == '' and $message_error == '' and $attachment_error == '' and $checkbox1_error == ''){` to this `if (!isset($name_error) and !isset($email_error) and !isset($message_error) and !isset($attachment_error) and !isset($checkbox1_error)){`

Comment: But the problem is not there.. It's in checkbox validation :l

Comment: I update my code.Please check. I remove input_test() from code and removed PHP short tag. Thats all. Please check. I checked from my local server.

Comment: I am no sure why, but all of a sudden my code is working just how I wanted.. And that is with `if ($name_error == '' and $email_error == '' and $message_error == '' and $attachment_error == '' and $checkbox1_error == ''){`. I did try your code aswell, but it did not let me submit the post. Thankyou for you effort anyway.